# Self answered questions as examples

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, answers, self-answer

At times, my learning parters at the university have a hard time solving certain problems.

Is it legitimate to post a self answered question, to help them, and at the same time, help others with an example?

*I found no other convenient communication method which I can write math in.

Comment: If the main goal is to help those you are studying with, I would say no. If you feel that the question and answer will be useful for a wider audience, then it should be fine (note that if it is some very specific exercise, most people will probably find it too localized to be useful). For communicating with those you study with, there are plenty of better options.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What options could you suggest? Because writing math in Skype is painful.

Comment: @NightRa I and my friends have been using http://mathim.com with great pleasure.

Comment: For long things, make it a .pdf and send it to them. For shorter things, make your own chatroom here and use the bookmarklet to enable MathJax, or write things on mathbin.net.

Comment: If you think that collaboratively editing a document would suit your purposes, [there are tools for it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online). If you want use TeX in some chat client, you can find [several solutions for that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81365/chatting-about-mathematics-with-real-time-latex-rendering). [This post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49384/tools-for-long-distance-collaboration) discusses several other possible solutions.

Comment: You can find several alder discussions about answering your own questions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/views-on-asking-and-answering-questions-solely-to-make-results-available-on-stac) and in the linked posts.

Comment: @Lord_Farin That's really excellent, so much so that I think you should offer it as an answer in its own right.

Comment: @user1296727 Done.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but Facebook Messenger now supports $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 4):

If you are intending to communicate in real-time with a small(ish) group of people, [MathIM.com](http://mathim.com) provides you with an IRC-like client capable of rendering maths.

Alternative chat solutions are described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81365/43351); it's just that I have good experience with MathIM myself.

---

For non-real-time communication, use $\LaTeX$ and distribute the resulting PDFs to the relevant people.

---

[Martin Sleziak's comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10898#comment41124_10898) contains pointers to threads with more options.

Comment: The "Quickie" option is really neat. I'll be talking about this around the department this week. Cool.